# When we can use the construction ...로 하여금?

Tags: verb

그로 하여금 편지를 쓰게 하다 - to make him write a letter.

Can't we just use 그가 편지를 쓰게 하다?

Answer (score 2):

I think 하여금 sounds very formal, and rarely used in conversation.  It's more commonly used in "serious" topics, like politics.  Random examples found on the web:

> 교육은 홍익인간(弘益人間)의 이념 아래 모든 국민으로 **하여금** 인격을 도야(陶冶)하고 자주적 생활능력과 민주시민으로서 필요한 자질을 갖추게 함으로써 인간다운 삶을 영위하게 하고 민주국가의 발전과 인류공영(人類共榮)의 이상을 실현하는 데에 이바지하게 함을 목적으로 한다.

> 그러나 이런 식의 발언에 강하게 고개를 가로 저을 뿐만 아니라 그런 무책임한 태도야말로 정부로 **하여금** 국민을 더욱 더 우롱하게 만드는 요인이 된다며 오히려 역정을 내는 일군의 경제학자들이 있다.

> 동기는 '개인으로 **하여금** 무엇인가를 시작하게 하고, 그것을 지속적으로 추구하게 하며, 시작한 과제를 완성하도록 이끄는 힘'이다.

Answer (score 0):

Both "그로 하여금 편지를 쓰게 하다" and "그가 편지를 쓰게 하다" are correct and mean the same thing. => make him write a letter.